# Safe to update git?

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Git for Windows was installed as part of Visual Studio 2013. I think it is version 1.8.3 if I remember correctly. There are newer versions available. Is it safe to update git or will internal setting of Visual Studio get corrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had Git for Windows installed before I installed VS2013. I've been running 1.9.4 the whole time and never had an issue with VS2013 interfacing with Git. Updating Git externally of VS shouldn't be a problem, most likely VS just interfaces with a known Git repository and doesn't have a dependency on the Git version it self. If the newer version of Git has a new feature you want to use and VS doesn't support it then VS won't break, you will just have to run the command through the Git instead of through the VS GUI.